# Check if Element exists in XML File using attribute as identifier

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to check if an `Element` exists by using the attribute `uuid`.

Here's an example how the file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test1>
<typ>task</typ>
  <datestamp>20150602153306</datestamp>
  <datecreate>20150602153306</datecreate>
<task uuid="92F7F685-C370-4E55-9026-020E3CDCEDE0" status="0">
    <task_headline>TEST2000</task_headline>
    <task_subject>There is a Problem.</task_subject>
    <task_action>Solve it!</task_action>
    <task_priority color="#E62C29">high</task_priority>
    <task_note></task_note>
</task>
<task uuid="92F7F685-C370-4E55-4464-ADWI290ASD" status="0">
    <task_headline>TEST3000</task_headline>
    <task_subject>Another Problem</task_subject>
    <task_action>Solve it again.</task_action>
    <task_priority color="#E62C29">high</task_priority>
    <task_image></task_image>
</task>
</Test1>
```

The Elements that will be tested are `<task_note></task_note>` and `<task_image></task_image>`

As you can see, the first `task` has the `<task_note>` and is missing the `<task_image>` element. How can I check if `<task_image>` exists, and when not create the element.

I know how to create an Element:

```
note.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(taskItems.get(position).get(task_note)));
```

**EDIT:**

Thats the Code I use

```
File fileDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "job_active");
fileDir.mkdirs();
int position = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);
HashMap<String, String> intentmap = (HashMap<String, String>) data.getSerializableExtra("
                    taskItems.set(position, intentmap);
try {
   DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(fileDir, filenameWithExt)));
   XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
   XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
   XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("//task[@uuid='" + taskItems.get(position).get(task_uuid) + "']/task_
                        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

   NodeList taskList = doc.getElementsByTagName("task");
   int taskListLength = taskList.getLength();
   String uuid = taskItems.get(position).get(task_uuid);
   for (int i = 0; i < taskListLength; i++) {
                            Node node = taskList.item(i);
                            Node key = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("uuid");
                            if (key != null && uuid.equals(key.getNodeValue())) {
                                Node valueNode = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("task_status");
                                valueNode.setTextContent("1000");
                            }
                            //Wenn die knoten task_note und task_image existieren sollen sie verändert werden
                            if (task_note.equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                                node.setTextContent(taskItems.get(position).get(task_note));
                            }
                            if (task_image.equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                                node.setTextContent(taskItems.get(position).get(task_image));
                            }
                        }

                        if(nodeList==null){
                            Node tasknote = doc.createElement(task_note);
                            tasknote.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(taskItems.get(position).get(task_note)));

                        }

                        NodeList tasknote = doc.getElementsByTagName(task_note);

                        if (tasknote == null) {
                            Element note = doc.createElement(task_note);
                            if (taskItems.get(position).containsKey(task_note))
                                if (taskItems.get(position).get(task_note) != null)
                                    note.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(taskItems.get(position).get(task_note)));
                            // task.appendChild(note);
                        }

                        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.
                        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileDir, filenameWithExt)));
                        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

But I don't know how to check if element exists using the `uuid` attribute.

I hope you can help me!

Kind Regards!

Comment: what xml parser are you using?

Comment: I've added my code i use for adding text content to existing elements